# Picard-Fuchs equations for modular functions

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, cv.complex-variables, modular-forms, differential-equations

Hello, MathOverflow community!

Suppose we have a modular curve of genus $0$, whose rational function field is generated by the modular function $f$. We can view $f$ as the parameter for some pencil of elliptic curves over $\mathbb{C}$. Under certain conditions, it is possible to express $f$ as the inverse function of the ratio of two linearly independent solutions of a second-order linear differential equation. The prototypical example is the case of the period integrals of the Legendre elliptic curve $y^2=x(x-1)(x-\lambda)$, which satisfy the Fuchsian equation $$\lambda(1-\lambda)D^2y + (1-2\lambda)Dy - y/4=0,$$ where $D=d/d\lambda$. We can interpret this differential equation as measuring the variation of the periods of an elliptic curve, as the parameter $\lambda$ changes.

Now my question is : have other Picard-Fuchs equations been calculated for modular functions? In principle, there should be many such equations; the Picard-Fuchs equation for Klein's $j$ function, without the calculation, is given in ([Harnad, McKay](http://arxiv.org/abs/solv-int/9902013)). I have seen the calculation for the $\lambda$ case carried out in a few books. But I have not seen such equations for the Hauptmodul associated to the other genus $0$ modular curves.

Any thoughts, comments, questions or references are much appreciated.

Please be kind, as I am only an undergraduate. (There seems to be much "tough love" here!)

Comment: Just to clarify (as I don't know your background in algebraic geometry and cohomology), for any family of smooth projective varieties parameterized by a variety $V$ there is a Picard-Fuchs PDE over $V$ expressing variation of the periods of deRham cohomology of the fibers (in fixed degree, such as degree 1 in the elliptic curve cases) as the base parameter changes. So your question is to make explicit a structure that always exists, not finding an ad hoc definition in each case. I guess Klein et al. worked it all out. I don't know a undergrad-level reference on this viewpoint of Picard-Fuchs. 

Comment: I'd suggest looking at work of Verrill and Doran.  There are some articles in the CRM proceedings edited by McKay and Sebbar.  There is also a brief description in Zagier's part of *1-2-3 of Modular forms*.

Comment: Boyarksy : thank you for your clarification. My background is not very strong, and I'm mostly relying on intuition here. I will soon be attempting to get a more technical grasp on my own question.

Scott : many thanks, I will check out the references you mention.

Answer (score 6):

Brief answer: yes, there are a lot of articles where the computations are done. I even don't know where to start. The work of Helena Verrill and Chuck Doran as well as Zagier's lectures in the *1-2-3 of modular forms* (mentioned by Scott Carnahan) are a definite must. In my [joint work with G. Almkvist and D. van Straten](http://www.mpim-bonn.mpg.de/preprints/send?bid=4023) this question is addressed as well and you will find some relevant references there (for example, to Don's Apery-like article). A lot of modular cases with the corresponding Picard--Fuchs differential equations are discussed in my other joint paper with Heng Huat Chan http://dx.doi.org/10.1112/S0025579309000436">[Mathematika **56**:1 (2010) 107--117] and in a recent preprint *New analogues of Clausen's identities arising from the theory of modular forms* (which I am not allowed to distribute publicly). You may also check Robert S. Maier's [arXiv:math/0501425](http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0501425) and his other publications.

I have to add the books which cover in full the hypergeometric differential equations uniformized by modular functions: [J.M. Borwein and P.B. Borwein, *Pi and the AGM; A study in analytic number theory and computational
complexity* (Wiley, New York, 1987)] and [M. Yoshida, *Hypergeometric functions, my love.
Modular interpretations of configuration spaces*, Aspects of Mathematics **E32** (Friedr. Vieweg & Sohn, Braunschweig, 1997)].

Comment: @Bruno: Since you are in Montreal, you can contact John McKay towards your question. As for your request to be kind, I highly recommend you Yoshida's book---I use it for my lectures in hypergeometric functions and modular forms. (It's out of print however, but please e-contact me directly if you have problems with access to the book.)

Answer (score 2):

See the following papers as well...

1. [Linear Ordinary Differential
   Equations Satisfied by Modular
   Forms](http://www.mmrc.iss.ac.cn/pub/mm25.pdf/7.pdf) by Xiaolong Ji and Yujie
   Ma
2. [Modular Functions and Their
   Differential Equations](http://people.brandeis.edu/~lian/Schiff.pdf) by Joshua
   L. Wiczer See also
   http://arxiv.org/PS_cache/math/pdf/0611/0611291v1.pdf
3. MR2031441 (2005b:11049)  Yang, Yifan
   . *On differential equations
   satisfied by modular forms.* Math. Z.
   246  (2004),  no. 1-2, 1--19.